# What does std::shared_ptr<T> sp(sp2, ptr) does?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, shared, standard-library

Digging deep into [C++ Standard Library](http://www.cppstdlib.com/) , I have found the following `shared_ptr` constructor overload, see the image attached.

[image]

Can anyone explain how sp can share ownership with another sp and refer to ptr??
I cant understand the concept, help please.